# how to fix this error "if -(num[i] + num[j]) in [lambda index: del num[index] for index in sorted(indexes, reverse=True)]:"

Tags: python, arrays, lambda

how to fix this line error

```
num = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]          
indexes = [i,j]          
if -(num[i] + num[j]) in [lambda index: del num[index] for index in sorted(indexes, reverse=True)]:                    
        return something
```

My goal is wondering whether exists a -(num[i] + num[j]) in num array without num[i] and num[j], meanwhile don't change the structure of the num array.

Comment: Can you paste formatted code in the post, it is currently unreadable and un-editable..

Comment: What is `num`? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Please indent your code so the SO formatter can display it correctly.

Comment: thx dirn, help me indent my code, this is my first time to ask question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do it manually:

```
target = -(num[i] + num[j])
for index, value in enumerate(num):
  if index in [i, j]:
    continue
  if value == target:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: yes, you are right, i have solved my problem using your method, successed....thanks a lot